# package acro does not work with biblatex anymore

Tags: biblatex, acro

I used to use the acro package for managing my acronyms and I also used acronyms in my bibliography which I compile with biblatex/biber. After updating MikTeX packages this doesn't work anymore. Here is my minimal example:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-bib.bib}
@Book{TEST,
  author    = {{\acs{ISO} X}},
  title     = {You name it},
  year      = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{zref,
            xkeyval,
            ifpdf,
            ifthen,
            calc,
            marginnote,
            datetime2,
            refcount,
            soulpos}%suggested to use with acronym

\addbibresource{\jobname-bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{ISO}{International Organization for Standardization}
\end{acronym}

This is text and I want to cite with acronyms: \cite{TEST}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Compiling ends with:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.27       }
```

?

Comment: See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/216, https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/215 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/727. The fix for https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/210 caused this regression.

Comment: That's actually the [`acronym`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package in your example not the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) package (although possibly a similar problem occurs with `acro`).

Comment: At least temporarily you might try using [backed=bibtex] rather than [backend=biber].

Comment: This will work again in Biber 2.12, see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/216