# Biblatex 3.11: author = {{\textsc{...}}, breaks compilation

Tags: biblatex

## Problem statement

After my recent upgrade to TeXLive 2018 (and hence to Biblatex version 3.11), the presence of a `\textsc` command inside a *double-braced* `author` field of a bibliography entry causes a compilation error due to an extra `}` in the `.bbl` file

This error did not occur in previous versions of Biblatex. I am looking for a workaround to this problem, ideally without having to change a significant number of entries in my `.bib` file.

## Minimal (non-)working example (MWE)

### .tex file

Save the following to `my.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{my.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Foo}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

### .bib file

Save the following to `my.bib`:

```
@misc{Foo,
        author = {{\textsc{Foo} bla}},
        title = {Bla},
        date = {1901},
}
```

### Compilation and error message

Compile via

```
pdflatex my
biber my
pdflatex my
```

which yields the following **error message**:

```
(./my.bbl
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

Upon inspection, the offending code in the `.bbl` file seems to indeed feature one `}` too many:

```
[...]
\name{author}{1}{}{%
{{uniquename=0,uniquepart=base,hash=4e64a6262beef2c23e5c3d6f48023844}{%
           family={{\textsc{Foo} bla}},
           familyi={\textsc{Foo} bla}\bibinitperiod}}}%
}
[...]
```

### Conditions under which error occurs

The error *only* occurs

- If the `author` field is enclosed by double braces: `author = {{...}},`
- In the presence of a `\textsc{}` (or `\scshape`) command within such an `author` field
- In Biblatex 3.11 (it did not occur before the recent upgrade)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425947/35864

Comment: I have updated my answer to the linked question with a workaround in case you can not refrain from using macros in name fields.

Comment: May I ask what the real-world use case is here? Maybe there is an altogether more elegant method to do away with the macro entirely (there probably is not, but I'm still intrigued).

Comment: The primary use case is that I'd like to `\textsc` company names in author fields, e.g., `author = {{\textsc{Akg} Acoustics}}` as opposed to `author = {{AKG Acoustics}}`. I have a hard time thinking about a way to entirely prevent the macro in this case - how else would one be able to define which part of the company name `\textsc` applies to?

Comment: No in that case a macro really is the only sensible solution. I just wanted to make sure that you are not doing terrible things like `author = {{\textsc{Elk}, Anne}}`. Or used the macro in ways where they could be removed as in `author = {{\textsc{NASA}}}` (you could use a name annotation to tell us that we are dealing with an acronym and act accordingly).

Comment: Right, thanks for checking that :) Also, I can now confirm that `author = {family={\textsc{Akg} Acoustics}},` works as a workaround (as you suggested at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425950/38212)